# setBackgroundColor in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-button

[image]

In this simple game I want to change the background color of the button that I press. But I get the following result, the buttons appearance becomes not good (the shape becomes different):

```
pressedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Is there a nicer way to do that? Thanks.

[Edit: my full code]

```
package com.example.xo_game;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button[] btns;
    char[][] gameState = new char[3][3];
    char turn = 'X';

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button[] btns = new Button[9];

        btns[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btns[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btns[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        btns[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btns[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btns[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);

        btns[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btns[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btns[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            btns[i].setTag(i);
            btns[i].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            gameState[i / 3][i % 3] = 'E';
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button pressedButton = (Button) v;

            int indexOfPressedButton = Integer.parseInt(pressedButton.getTag()
                    .toString());

            int row = indexOfPressedButton / 3;
            int col = indexOfPressedButton % 3;

            if (gameState[row][col] != 'E')
                return;

            gameState[row][col] = turn;

            String turnAsString = String.valueOf(turn);

            pressedButton.setText(turnAsString);

            if (turn == 'X') {
                pressedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                turn = 'O';
            } else {
                pressedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                turn = 'X';
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: post edited, I added the full code.

Comment: thanks for asking - that was exactly my question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
pressedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: PorterDuff class is not defined. Should I import something?

Comment: import android.graphics.PorterDuff;

Answer (score 6):

create selector file any name like button_selector.xml in drawable folder

**Edited with Gradient**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <gradient android:startColor="#ad1c1c" android:endColor="#cc3737" android:angle="90"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#7d0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <gradient android:startColor="#cfcfcf" android:endColor="#ebebeb" android:angle="90"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#8f8f8f"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then set in button background

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but really I got almost the previous result.

Comment: If it's correct then you have to accept one of the answer which nearest to your solution

Comment: I'm trying all of the answers one after another. So far, all of them change the shape of the button into a square.

Answer (score 1):

As @pratik said save this **button.xml** in drawable folder

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#222"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f1f1f1"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#222"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Apply this button as background

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

and in your class file do like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

  pressedButton.setPressed(true);
}
```

so that the red color will be stable

Comment: hmmm copy the answer keep it but you need trick to uncaught by origin user by changing the copied answer with some another value

Answer (score 0):

try this :

you have create like this in the ImageButton xml

create xml file using the button image like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/backbutton" />
<item 
android:drawable="@drawable/closebutton" />
</selector>
```

add that xml file as background for IMageButton

```
<ImageButton                 
android:layout_height="50px" 
android:layout_width="50px" 
android:id="@+id/settings" 
android:background="@drawable/settings_button" //setting_button in
                                                     the xml file            
android:text="Settings"/>
```