# Changing the paint color of a custom view

Tags: android, colors

I'm trying to dynamically change the color of a custom view but I can't figure out what needs to be accessed and set to achieve this. Here is my code:

```
Context context;
RectView rv;
LinearLayout ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_debug);

    context = this;

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.debugLayout);

    rv = new RectView(context, 0, 100, 0, 100, true, false, "06:45 PM");
    ll.addView(rv);
    ll.postInvalidate();

}

public void changeColor(View view){

    //Color change code goes here

}

private class RectView extends View{

    float leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY;
    boolean isAppt;
    boolean isBeforeTime;
    public Paint rectPaint;
    private RectF rectangle;
    String time;

    public RectView(Context context, float _leftX, float _rightX, float _topY, float _bottomY,
            boolean _isAppt, boolean _isBeforeTime, String _time){
        super(context);
        leftX = _leftX;
        rightX = _rightX;
        topY = _topY;
        bottomY = _bottomY;
        isAppt = _isAppt;
        isBeforeTime = _isBeforeTime;
        time = _time;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        rectPaint = new Paint();

        if(leftX > rightX || topY > bottomY)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Left = " + leftX + ", Top = " + topY + ", Right = " + rightX +
                ", Bottom = " + bottomY);
        rectangle = new RectF(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY);

        float height = bottomY;
        float width = rightX - leftX;
        MyUtility.LogD_Common("Height = " + height + ", Width = " + width);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int) height);
        params.leftMargin = (int) leftX;
        //params.rightMargin = 10;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public void setBeforeTime(boolean _isBeforeTime){
        isBeforeTime = _isBeforeTime;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        if(isAppt){
            if(isBeforeTime)
                rectPaint.setARGB(144, 119, 98, 95);
            else
                rectPaint.setARGB(144, 217, 131, 121);
            //119,98,95
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
        else{
            rectPaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
        if(isAppt){
            rectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle, rectPaint);
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/debugLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change color"
        android:onClick="changeColor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Since I'm not setting the background I can't get the background and change the color that way. The rectangle also needs to have both the stroke and the fill and be created dynamically. How do I go about changing the fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the background color of the view? If so, try

```
view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

OR

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```

These posts might help:

[How to set background color of a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view)

[SetBackgroundColor in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615720/setbackgroundcolor-in-android)

Comment: In the code posted above I am setting the paint color when I create the rectangle for the first time. I want to change that paint color and re-draw the rectangle; however, calling `rv.setBeforeTime(true); ll.postInvalidate();` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to remove the rectangle and draw a new one. [Add and Remove Views in Android Dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically/3995335#3995335)

Comment: Another weird thing is that the code works fine on the emulator but doesn't work on an actual device. And yes that is what I might want to try.

Comment: May I know which device you're using?

Comment: Removing and adding the view seems to be working. Thank you for your help.